# Trigger implementation , did i do it properly?

Tags: mysql, trigger

```
FOLDER(CodFO,name,path,dim,ContainerFolder)
FILE(CodFI,name,CodFO,path,dateC,dateE,dim)
```

After a file is inserted into the FILE class , its path field gets updated after the instert in a way that it has to be the concatenation of the path of the container folder and of the name of the file itself.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckPath
AFTER INSERT  ON file OF path
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SELECT CodFI , CodFO
    FROM Folder as FO JOIN File as FI ON FO.CodFO=FI.CodFO
    GROUP BY CodFI;
    
    INSERT INTO FILE 
    VALUES (New.CodFI,New.name,New.path,New.dateC,New.dateE,New.dim)
END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make mysql trigger to access another table's entry?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303305/how-to-make-mysql-trigger-to-access-another-tables-entry)

Comment: Databases don't have the concept of "class".  What is meant by "FILE class"?

Comment: FILE is a tab containing a PrimaryKey (CodFi) a name to the file itself (name) , a foreign key (CodFo) , a path , a creation date and an end date , and dimension in Kb .